# JSF Configuration issue in Eclipse Galelio

Tags: java, jsf

I need to configure jsf with eclpse galelio, am followed the same steps given [here](http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaServerFaces/article.html)

I have working java runtime environment and tomcat server and worked with jsp without any problem.

after configuring the jsf i got the following stack trace when running my page(The similar described in that tutorial).

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Class org.apache.myfaces.orchestra.lib.jsf.OrchestraFacesContextFactory is no javax.faces.context.FacesContextFactory
at javax.faces.FactoryFinder.newFactoryInstance(FactoryFinder.java:164)
at javax.faces.FactoryFinder.getFactory(FactoryFinder.java:136)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.init(FacesServlet.java:137)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1213)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1026)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4421)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4734)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:840)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:754)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
12 Dec, 2013 11:16:44 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext loadOnStartup
SEVERE: Servlet /MyWebApp threw load() exception
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Class org.apache.myfaces.orchestra.lib.jsf.OrchestraFacesContextFactory is no javax.faces.context.FacesContextFactory
at javax.faces.FactoryFinder.newFactoryInstance(FactoryFinder.java:164)
at javax.faces.FactoryFinder.getFactory(FactoryFinder.java:136)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.init(FacesServlet.java:137)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1213)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1026)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4421)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4734)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:840)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:754)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
```

I can run the app by deploying it in my tomcat , but it is wasting time a lot.

Please tell me what can I do to run my application in eclipse itself...

Thanks in advance........

Comment: it seems like a lib files not included in path issue... please include them.. ( myfaces.orchestra.lib )

Comment: @ AurA I checked for path issues but I can't find why it is happen?